# Curvature of an affine system

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, general-relativity

Recently, I find an interesting [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.5318) that mentioned the Definition of curvature of an affine optimal control system. It suddenly reminded me that many textbooks on Riemannian geometry only tell us about metrics, geodesics, parallel transport, and curvature tensors and son on, using some special surfaces with constant curvature as examples. So for a general control system, how do we calculate its curvature tensor? Is this a problem worth studying? Are there any more examples?

Thank you all for your comments and help!

Comment: What can be said depends on the scope of the definition of "general control system" you are using.

Comment: @TravisWillse Thank you, do you have specific examples?

Comment: A spectacular and historically important example is the control system of one surface rolling on another without slipping or twisting. Under a simple genericity condition, the system is completely nonholonomic and defines a $2$-plane field $D$ on a $5$-dimensional configuration space $M$ that is maximally nonintegrable in the sense that $[D, [D, D]] = TM$. The fundamental curvature of this geometry is a binary quartic form on $D$, i.e., a section of $S^4 D^*$. Surprisingly, the largest possible symmetry group of such a distribution is an exceptional simple Lie group of type $\mathrm{G}_2$.

Comment: In fact, this control system entails a little more structure, namely, the above $2$-plane distribution together with a fiber metric on $D$ (a "sub-Riemannian metric"), and the appropriate notion of curvature that takes into account this extra data is different from the binary quartic mentioned above. In general, different geometries (hence different classes of control systems) can have widely varying curvature quantities.